# ionic alertcontroller blocking page refresh

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic-Angular. The thing is I've a matautocomplete along with icon. When you select a value in matautocomplete, a list is shown below. On icon click I'm showing ionic alertcontroller and on selecting ok, setting the value of matautocomplete programmatically. Though value is getting set in matautocomplete but list is not refreshing. Then when I again click on icon or change window even, the list refreshes.

```css
async showBranches() {
    // this.autocomplete.closePanel();
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Branch Locations',
      inputs: this.branchArray,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "CANCEL",
          handler: data => {
            console.log("cancel clicked");
          }
        },
        {
          text: "OK",
          handler: data => {
            console.log("branchId: " + data);
            this.branchID = data;
            this.setBlankOrSelectedBranch();
            
          }
        }],
      cssClass: 'alertCustomCss'
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

```html
<div class="col90">
              <mat-form-field class="fullWidth">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Select Branch Location" matInput [formControl]="myBranch"
                  [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)='onBranchSelected($event.option.value)'>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of filteredBranches | async" [value]="branch">
                    {{branch.branchName}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>
              </mat-form-field>
              <ion-icon name="finger-print" matSuffix class="thumb" (click)="showBranches()"></ion-icon>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous operations may not trigger Angular to re-render the view, you can try to manually notify Angular to re-render

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public _ngZone:NgZone){}

public refresh() {
  this._ngZone.run(() => {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Should I add this in `handler: data =>` inside showBranches() method?

Comment: Anyway. I figured it out. Thank you so much. Now its working. You made my day.